# JS: How to convert list item to lowercase and use it to get key from an object?

Tags: javascript, json, lowercase

I have a list and an object and I would like to use a list value to get one of the keys' values.

```
let devices = ['001A2208B97D','001A2208C9FA','001A2214ADC8','001A2214A73A','001A2214B86E','001A2214A6DF','001A2214ADBF','001A2208CFD3']
let entities = ['Temperature', 'Valve', 'Battery', 'Offset']
let temperature = { device_class: 'temperature', icon: "hass:thermometer-bluetooth", unit: "°C"}
let valve = { device_class: '', icon: "hass:valve", unit: "%"}
let battery = { device_class: 'battery', icon: "hass:battery-bluetooth", unit: ""}
let offset = { device_class: '', icon: "hass:offset", unit: "°C" }

for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < entities.length; j++) {
        msg.payload = {
            "icon": temperature['icon'],
            "unit_of_measurement": temperature['unit'],
            "state_class": "measurement",
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `entities` is lower case, so before getting the value from `temperature`, I need to convert to lower case.

I tried `entities[0].toLowerCase()['unit']` and `entities[0.toLowerCase()]['unit']` and `(entities[0].toLowerCase())['unit']` and I have run out of ideas.

Does anybody know how to do this correctly? Ideally in a one liner, i.e. without first creating a new list or dict with all the lower case value. On the fly if possible :)

Comment: You can't/won't create an object with `temperature` in it instead of having a variable? like `const data = {"temperature" : { icon: "mdi:thermometer-bluetooth", unit: "°C" }}`? If you can create that, it will be really easy for you to work with. Otherwise you have to use something like the unsafe `eval` to evaluate your string to the variable.

Comment: `temperature` is the name of a variable, you can access the unit like `temperature.unit`. Its not clear from your question what you are trying to access

Comment: You may mean `window[entities[0].toLowerCase()].unit` to get the unit from the window variable called `temperature`.

Comment: Also you do not have `a JSON` - you have an object. [This is JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: Are you really saying that if you were to Google "JavaScript I need to convert to lower case", that you didn't find anything?! We expect that you'll do your research before posting here. Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be a tutorial site.

Comment: *Ideally in a one liner,...*  <--- Don't worry about how many lines it takes initially. First, get it working, then optimize. Trying to optimize while trying to make it work is a big "no, no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code exists in the global scope, the variable "temperature" will exist as a property of the "window" object, so you could request it like this:

```js
window.temperature
```

Or this:

```js
window["temperature"]
```

Or this:

```js
var entity = "Temperature"
window[entity.toLowerCase()]
```

So your code might look like this:

```js
let entities = ['Temperature', 'Valve', 'Battery', 'Offset']
let temperature = { icon: "mdi:thermometer-bluetooth", unit: "°C" }

msg.topic = window[entities[0].toLowerCase()]['unit']
```

But if this code is not in the global scope, such as in a function, it would work if you put the "temperature" variable inside another object, like this:

```js
let entities = ['Temperature', 'Valve', 'Battery', 'Offset']
let stuff = {
  temperature: { icon: "mdi:thermometer-bluetooth", unit: "°C" }
}

msg.topic = stuff[entities[0].toLowerCase()]['unit']
```

(disclaimer: this code is completely untested)

Comment: I updated my initial post with more code. I hope this makes it clearer. I did not want to spam too much with too much code and make it difficult to read.
I will test the with both of Magmatic's approaches.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my comment

Comment: EDIT: I created a new object per your recommendations and it worked perfectly!

Thank you all for your fast support :)

Comment: Or, just `temperature`.

Comment: @Scott Marcus: I am iterating through the entities, so they won't all be temperature ;-). And as I said, I did search and I did try different approaches. And I have used this successfully before, but if you looked at my code and my problem you would see that this is a special case not covered in any examples I could find.

Comment: @AleXSR700 The comment was for Magnatic to add to his examples of how to call a global.